# Python: remove any character that comes directly after a specific set of characters from a string

Tags: python, string

Here is my original string:

```
string = '<div id="2">\n\t<h1 id="25"> id="234">\n\t\'
```

I want to remove all of the id numbers so the string reads:

```
string = '<div id="">\n\t<h1 id=""> id="">\n\t\'
```

So basically, I want to remove anything between:

```
id="
```

and

```
"
```

Comment: You are expected to provide the code you tried to solve this problem and explain what did not work. Otherwise, this just looks like a requirements dump with no effort. See [mcve]

Comment: @Lexi Ok. I did try some stuff to no success. I will edit the post to include what did not work. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
string = '<div id="2">\n\t<h1 id="25"> id="234">\n\t'
final_data  = re.sub('(?<=id\=")\d+(?=")', '', string)
```

Output:

```
'<div id="">\n\t<h1 id=""> id="">\n\t'
```

Answer (score 1):

I first had to place it into 3 double quotes, otherwise I got error:

```
string = """<div id="2">\n\t<h1 id="25"> id="234">\n\t\
...: """
import re
erase = re.compile(r'"\d+"')
string2 = erase.sub('""',string)
```

This way you replace all the numbers between double quotes. Output:

```
'<div id="">\n\t<h1 id=""> id="">\n\t'
```